# How to use share this link for google plus & pinterest?

Tags: php, javascript, share

I have to share the product title, product image and product description in Google plus.

I have this code which only shares the URL but not the image and description.

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=<<Encoded URL>>;
```

In Pinterest, I have a script which only shares one image. How can I pass multiple images in Pinterest?

```
http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<<Encoded URL>>&media=<<Encoded 1 IMAGE URL>>&description=<<Encoded Description>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to make changes in meta tags for sharing purpose such as:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="YOUR IMAGE LINK HERE" />
 <meta name="description" content="YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE" />
```

I am sure for facebook.com but not for google plus. You may try it.